# Couldn't run PowerShell script using batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I wrote a PowerShell script to give run access to run without admin privilege. So I need to run that script from batch file. Here I attached my PowerShell script and my batch file. I am not able to run the PowerShell script from my batch file.

Access.ps1

```powershell
powershell -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force" -Verb RunAs
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Unicorn",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::ChangePermissions)
$acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule (".\USERS","FullControl",@("ObjectInherit","ContainerInherit"),"None","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$key.SetAccessControl($acl)

Write-Host "Successfully set permission to PM Registry!"
```

Access.bat

```batch
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
PAUSE
```

This is the error

[image]

Comment: Does `Access.ps1` really start with `powershell -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*`, or is that a copy-paste error? Please [edit] the question if it's an error. Also, what happens? Is there an error message? Nothing? Wrong output?

Comment: @vonPryz updated error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your system, the execution of PowerShell scripts is not allowed. Either allow it, by executing (with administrative privileges):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Or bypass it (in your `.bat`):

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\Access.ps1
```

Inside `Access.ps1`, the following line is pretty much useless:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force" -Verb RunAs
```

as you already need permissions to execute scripts to run this script.

Comment: I followed your second option then I have the below output

The argument '.\Access.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter. @Thomas

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145

Comment: @LasalSenarath Well, you have to provide the correct path to your script, of course. `.\Access.ps1` is a relative path and means, that this file is expected to be inside your working directory.

Comment: Both files(.bat and .ps1) are in same directory as other dll files. The last line of .ps can be seen in output. Can you give me an example to put an absolute path inside bat file @Thomas

Comment: This directory should then also be your working directory. An absolute path looks like this: `C:\Users\LasalSenarath\Desktop\scripts\Access.ps1`.

Comment: It is not working below output happened @Thomas
The argument '%~dpn0.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.

Comment: It is not a problem  I put "PowerShell -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*" inside .ps1 file so both relative and absolute path is working this solution. Thank you @Thomas